# Firebase time duration overlap check

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a room reservation app where a user can reserve the room for any duration during the day.
If there already exists a booking on the server, you cannot book during that time.

For example,
Sally books Room A from 1 PM to 3 PM.
Danny wants to book the same room from 2 PM to 4 PM.

For obvious reasons(Namely TICTOU), I want to avoid client side validation. How would I write this up in the rules?

I have a naive solution that I want to avoid below.

1. client saves the entry.
2. Cloud function's onWrite iterates through the database on that day to make sure there are no other events that overlap.
3. If it can be saved, Set "validated" flag on the data to be true. If not, set it to false, then delete the data.
4. At this point, save is legitimately finished.
5. Client-side receives "validated = false" flag as an update and display an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends a bit on the data structure. For example, if you decide that rooms can only be booked in slots of an hour (starting on the hour), then you can model the reservations like this:

```
reservations: {
  room1: {
    "2018-01-09": {
      "13": "UidOfSally",
      "14": "UidOfSally"
    }
  }
}
```

Now when Danny tries to book the room from 2-4 he sends this update statement:

```
reservations: {
  room1: {
    "2018-01-09": {
      "14": "UidOfDanny",
      "15": "UidOfDanny"
    }
  }
}
```

And you can validate it with security rules that simply check if the slot is already claimed:

```
{ "rules":{
  "reservations": {
    "$roomId": {
      "$date": {
        "$slot": {
          ".write": "!data.exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

You can make this write rule a lot more advanced to suit your needs. For example:

```
".write": "
  (!data.exists() && newData.val() == auth.uid) || ( // if no one has claimed this yet, any user can claim it for themselves
  ( data.exists() && data.val() == auth.uid) // owner can delete their reservation
)"
```

Your code should send the entire update from Danny in a single call (either as a transaction or as an `update()`), so that it always gets rejected or accepted in its entirety.

This approach can work with smaller slots too, they don't have to be hour longs. But they do have to be discrete slots.

Comment: That's also another naive solution I had thought about. My version had the time cut up into 5 minute chunks. it's the same approach but it becomes a bit messy/hacky. I guess this is just a limitation of the nosql concept. Thanks Frank for great answers! Much appreciated :)